# Exclude match in Vim with ‘\%’?

Tags: regex, vim, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like so:

```
productSku-1,attribute1,2,3
productSku-1,attribute4,5
productSku-1,attribute4,5
productSku-2,attribute1,2,3
productSku-2,attribute4,5
productSku-3,attribute1,1
```

I am trying to “collapse” the same product attributes into one line, while getting rid of the extra instances of `productSku`. So, I match product to the next line and then remove the next `productSku` lines as well as the line break to compress it into a single line. In the above example, the result should look like so:

```
productSku1,attribute1,2,3,attribute4,5,attribute4,5
productSku2,attribute1,2,3,attribute4,5
productSku3,attribute1,1
```

I thought the following substitution command would work, but I have never used the `\%` sign.

```
:%s/(^[A-Za-z0-9-]+)(.)((\%(\n\1)(.))+)/\1\2\3
```

I thought it would exclude the match from match `\3`… but it isn’t working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is like this:

```
:sort
qqjkdt,:g/<C-r>"/norm dt,-gJ<Enter>0P+q
10000@q
```

#### Step by step

`:sort` - sort all of the lines by productSku

`qq` - start a recording, see `:help qq`

`jk` - this is a little macro hack... if we get to the last line it will throw an error and the rest of the command won't execute.

`dt,` - delete the productSku

`:g/` - start a `:global` command, see `:help :global`

`<C-r>"` - insert the contents of the `"` register (the productSku we deleted)

`norm` - short for `:help :normal`

`dt,` - delete the productSku since we don't want them

`-` - go to the previous line

`gJ` - join the lines without any spaces

`<Enter>` - finish the `:global` command

`0P` - put the productSku back at the beginning of the line

`+` - move down one line

`q` - finish the recording

`10000@q` repeat the recording 10k times (or more if you need)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following efficient command.

```
:g/\%(^\1,.*\n\)\@<=\([^,]*\)/s/$/,/|-j!
```